# pull information from rails table and place into other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this

```
<%= simple_form_for @newevent do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :eventname %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.text_field :eventname, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control", value: "@newevent.product_name" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is in my edit.html.erb, You access this page from a table that has a button placed on it. This is where things loose me,

What i'm wanting is this.

When you click edit, The values will be loaded in from the first table, However when you click save it will save to the second table.

How do i go about this? the `:eventname` only exists in table two. In table one it is called `LocationName`

i have this in my update

```
  def update
    @newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @newevent.update_attributes(event_params.merge createdby: current_user.id)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to "/events"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Error updating event'
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Can you post code for your two tables? I'm a little unclear on your question.

Comment: The two db tables are huge? how do you want the code?

Comment: I thought you were referring to HTML tables, but you mean two database tables (i.e., two different rails models). So as I understand it, you don't really  want to create a form for editing an instance of the first model. What you want to do is create a new instance of the second model where the form defaults to values from the first table. Does that sound correct?